# SML: datatype declaration won't allow []

Tags: types, sml

The standard SML Basis `list` is defined as

```
datatype 'a list = [] | :: of 'a * 'a list
```

However, I get this error when I try to create my own list data type:

```
- datatype 'a mylist = [] | mycons of 'a * 'a mylist
 Error: syntax error found at LBRACKET
```

However, this works:

```
- datatype 'a mylist = Nil | mycons of 'a * 'a mylist;
datatype 'a mylist = Mycons of 'a * 'a mylist | Nil
```

But due to the lack of square brackets, this verson doesn't produce very list-like output:

```
- Mycons (1,Nil);
val it = Mycons (1,Nil) : int mylist
- Mycons (1, Mycons (1,Nil));
val it = Mycons (1,Mycons (1,Nil)) : int mylist
```

Why isn't SML accepting my original attempt with `[]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

> The standard SML Basis list is defined as
>
> ```
> datatype 'a list = [] | :: of 'a * 'a list
> ```

is not correct.

Rather, `list` is defined like this:

```
datatype 'a list = nil | :: of 'a * 'a list
```

and the `[foo, bar, baz]` notation is a special syntax (a "derived form") that the *Definition of Standard ML, Revised* explicitly defines (in Appendix A, on page 56) as being equivalent to `foo :: bar :: baz :: nil`.

---

For your type, you're not going to be able to redefine the `[...]` syntax — it is built into the language, and its meaning is fixed — but you can make your syntax at least *somewhat* friendlier by using a symbolic (non-alphanumeric) identifier and declaring it as infix and right-associative; for example:

```
infixr :::

datatype 'a my_list = MY_NIL | ::: of 'a * 'a my_list

val twoOnes = 1 ::: 1 ::: MY_NIL
```

Comment: As far as the `'a * 'a my_list` is concerned, this seems to be a tuple, so that if instead of infix `:::` we had the original `mycons`, we could have `mycons (1,Nil). Is this a correct assessment?